# Selector to return closest <tr> only if table has more than 2 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Is there a **selector** available in jQuery to do something like:

```
$(this).closest('tr:count(tr>2)');
```

Context of `this` is an `<input>` element within a `<td>`.

**Disclaimer:** I know this can be done with `.length` `.size` `.filter` `.not` etc but I wonder if there is a nice way to do this just using CSS selectors.

Comment: May I ask, what exactly is this for?

Comment: Native CSS selectors don't support selecting parent elements. Neither does jQuery's extension to the existing selector syntax allow you to do what you're asking, I think.

Comment: @Matti when the input button (remove row button) is clicked, it should remove that row but ONLY if it isn't the last remaining row in the table. The first <tr> is the header, so hence > 2.

Comment: Put @Matti and @Amadan's solutions together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't test, but probably

```
$(this).closest('tr:not(:only-child)')
```

assuming a `tr` will only have `tr` sisters, which is not unreasonable.

Comment: That ensures there is more than 1 row, but not necessarily more than 2 rows.

Comment: Yep BoltClock, it won't work unfortunately for > 2 rows but will for > 1. I did originally try this just in case. This will work if using Matti's technique of putting header into `<thead>` section

Comment: It's a shame jQuery doesn't have a `:more-than-child(2)` selector

Comment: Seems like the best solution if I put the head correctly into a <thead>

Comment: Yes. Sorry for misreading the question; indeed, the solution is the combination of @Matti's and mine :)

Answer (score 3):

Put your header in a `<thead>` and your rows in a `<tbody>`, as they should be. That way a simple selector such as <del>`tbody:has(tr)>tr` or</del> the one given by @Amadan will work.

(Ok, I didn't quite think that selector through...)

Comment: I would actually go with this. +1